# Проблема создании фрагментов

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Создал фрагмент через New - Fragment - Fragment(Blank) добавив в фрагмент пару кнопок и добавив этот фрагмент в основной layout при запуске у меня не запускается данное приложение. В чем проблема?

Разметка фрагмента:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.leo.myjustporject.FragmentButton">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Разметка активити:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.leo.myjustporject.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.example.leo.myjustporject.FragmentButton"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_button"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_button"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: А можно удивить разметку?

Comment: Также приложите код + сообщение об ошибке + тип ошибки и укажите однозначно строку возникновения оной

Comment: А скриншот можете удалить. Толку от него 0.

Comment: Обновил вопрос)

Comment: java код и стек трейс еще нужны